# SBT run single test class in submodule

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a multi module project with moduleA, moduleB, and moduleC. I want to run my class com.helpme.run.MyTest from moduleB.

My guess is the sbt command should look like:

sbt "project moduleA" --mainClass com.helpme.run.MyTest test

But no luck. Please help!! Thanks!

Comment: Run your class as a main class or run it as a test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you can run a test by using [`testOnly`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#testonly)

```
$ sbt testOnly MyTest
```

But if your project is a multi-project `sbt` project and you have the same test class with the same name in more than one project you can [navigate between projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Navigating+projects+interactively) by `project` command and then run the test

```
$ sbt
> project moduleA
> testOnly MyTest
```

Note that you have to first run `sbt` and then run the rest of commands from the `sbt` shell.

Comment: Reading `sbt` docs, especially [Testing part](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#testonly) is highly recommended.

Comment: How to select only one project *from the command line*. In maven it is -pl

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer: `project moduleA` command will switch you to `moduleA` project.

Comment: "project myproject". Yes I did try that and it *does* work. I did not realize one can string together sbt console commands on a command line by separating them by  semicolons. V cool.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your project configuration `testOnly` couldn't work

You can try this command too:

```sh
sbt "project myProject" "testOnly com.this.is.my.Test"
```